# asm little-endian register/immediate/memory order

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, printf, endianness

I'm quite new to assembler - I have only done some programming on 8-bit micro-controllers before.
Now I've problems to understand how litte-endian is stored. I already have read the article on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and some threads here but I'm still confused.

CPU: x64 
Compiler: yasm 
OS: Linux

Now the questions:

1. MOV r32,imm32:

   `section .bss
       var: resb 4             ;reserve 4 bytes
       varlen: equ $-var 

   section .text
   global _start 

   _start:
       MOV R10D, 0x6162630A
       MOV [var], R10D
       CMP R10B, 0x0A
       JNE nequal 

       MOV eax, 0x04 ;printf
       MOV ebx, 0x01 ;stdio
       MOV ecx, var
       MOV edx, varlen
       int 0x80      ;tell the kernel to print the msg 

   end:
       MOV eax, 0x01 ;return 0
       MOV ebx, 0x00
       int 0x80`

   output: 
   LF (linefeed - according to 0x0a)
   cba

   The code above shows that the constant is written to the register without byte-swapping  but why is printf reading from the highest memory address to the lowest??
   Why is the constant in the register not swapped according to little-endian? Is this compiler-dependent? 
   Is this correct:
   |61h|62h|63h|0Ah| .... the register
   31........................0 
   memory (adr increments in bytes) 
   adr, data
   0x00 61h
   0x01 62h
   0x02 63h
   0x03 0Ah
2. MOV r32, m32

   `section .data
       msg:   db 0x70,0x71,0x72,0x0a
       msglen:equ $-msg 

   section .text
   global _start 

   _start:
       MOV EAX, [msg]
       CMP AL, 0x70
       JNE end 

       MOV eax, 0x04
       MOV ebx, 0x01
       MOV ecx, msg
       MOV edx, msglen
       int 0x80 

   end:
       MOV eax, 0x01
       MOV ebx, 0x00
       int 0x80`

   output:
   pqrLF (LF represents a linefeed)

   Is this correct:
   |0Ah|72h|71h|70h| .... the register
   31........................0 
   memory (adr increments in bytes) 
   adr, data
   0x00 70h
   0x01 71h
   0x02 72h
   0x03 0Ah

Could this be a conclusion:
 Data in registers is BigEndian and in memory it's LittleEndian? 
Thank you for your responses. 
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking about endianness on registers makes no sense, as registers do not have memory addresses.

From your Wikipedia source: *"The terms endian and endianness refer to the convention used to interpret the bytes making up a data word **when those bytes are stored in computer memory**"*

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the quick response! Everything makes sense now.